# Access Error: 404 -- Not Found - CNR WebGUI

Tags: java, jsp

This is my first post here, I have been searching for solution on net for sometime now and so i will ask you experts to help me solve this issue.

So i have CNR (Cisco Network Registrar)

CNR uses WEBgui as their front-end application. So the issue is i get Access Error: 404 -- Not Found error and i am trying to find out what could have caused this to happen.

I looked at all the post on this site and they are related to some sort of codes that needs to be changed in order to work. Yet my situation is different. After the software was installed i have not perform any code changes to the software. The only possible cause of this failure could be the JRE/Java updates. Now,From CNR documents it clearly indicates that the latest JRE would work with CNR software. So at this point i don't know what to do and i turn to you guys.

1.OS: Windows XP
2.CNR Version: 6.3
3.JRE Version: 1.6.031 - Supposed to be latest
4.internet explorer version: 7
5.login address: http://127.0.0.1:8080/login.jsp

There has been no changes made to any of the .jsp or XML files. Let me know if you need any files or screen shots.

mark

Answer (score 0):

A quick look at the docs [here](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/net_mgmt/network_registrar/7.2/installation/guide/CNR72InstallGuide.pdf) says:

```
To access the web UI:
    http://hostname:http-port
    https://hostname:https-port
```

I don't see them talking about login.jsp (though it may direct you there)

Comment: Yes, Stuart i was just being extra informative since not everyone has CNR which is expensively crappy software to have. I would suggest a software with "real" interface then browser based crap. it make sense only from developer side not user side.

Comment: Is the `Network Registrar Local Server Agent` or `Network Registrar 
Regional Server Agent` started?

Comment: Stuart, The Network Registrar Local Server Agent is running and i have restart it. Still same issue.